# NSJSONSerialization fails while casting into Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>. Succeeds while casting into Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to Parse a json. Casting to [String,AnyObject?] fails. while [String,AnyObject] succeeds

```
   if let jsonDictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>  {
         print(jsonDictionary["output"])
   }
   else {
       print("Parsing Error")
   }
```

The above parsing fails, while the below succeeds

```
   if let jsonDictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>  {
         print(jsonDictionary["output"])
   }
   else {
       print("Parsing Error")
   }
```

I want to know why this happens.

Comment: What does the json look like?  And how does it fail?  What happens?

Comment: (As a note, since you're already `if let`-ing, you should probably `try?` instead of `try!`... and you should never `try!`).

Comment: {
                                "result":"success",
"translated_text":"\u0bb9\u0bb2\u0bc7\u0bbe"
 } this is the json

Comment: If it is optional binding then `try` is there no need of `?`

Answer (score 2):

By definition all keys and values in a Swift dictionary must be non-optional.

Swift dictionary is bridged to Foundation `NSDictionary` and there the documentation says

> Neither a key nor a value can be nil

By the way: In Swift setting a value for a given key to `nil` removes the key

Comment: from your explanation one key is removed what about the other keys?. will this cause whole json parse fail?

Comment: That means for example if you have a dictionary `["alpha" : 1, "beta" : 2]` and you write `dict["beta"] = nil` it's the same as `[dict removeObjectForKey:@"beta"]` in ObjC. The other keys are not affected.

Comment: So parsing will succeed anyway.. any clue why json parser fails here..i am using Swift 2.1

Comment: If `Parsing Error` is printed then the JSON object is not a dictionary. If the code crashes because of `try!` catch the error properly. If `nil` is printed then the key `output` does not exist.